# Position of adverb with respect to the adjective it modifies

Tags: grammaticality, adverbs

> The arm was **so badly injured** (a) that **he must have** (b) **it amputated** (c).

Which part of this sentence has an error?

Should it be "The arm was **injured so badly.**" Is that right?

Comment: The only error I can see is that there is no space after _“(b)”_. It would sound more natural to say “…that he had to have it amputated”, but there's no _error_ in the sentence as it stands.

Comment: Sounds like a homework Q to me.

Comment: I would say "The arm ***is*** so badly injured that he must have it amputated." or "The arm was so badly injured that he ***had to have*** it amputated." or "The arm ***is*** so badly injured that he ***will have to have*** it amputated." Alternatively "The arm was so badly injured that he must have ***really been in pain.***" ;-)

Answer (score 2):

As for adverb position, there is nothing wrong with **"so badly injured"**.  As a matter of fact it sounds more natural than **"injured so badly"**, which is not wrong.

- e.g. "His essay was **so badly written/written so badly** that I had to ask him to rewrite it."

I wouldn't use "must" in the past tense, and would add a possessive adjective at the beginning of the sentence.

- "His arm **is** so badly injured that he **must** have it amputated."
- "His arm **was** so badly injured that it **had to** be amputated."

As Andrew Leach has mentioned in a comment, if the victim is in hospital, and hasn't been operated on yet, it is perfectly grammatical to say **"His arm was..... and it must be amputated."**

Comment: *Must* **could** be present tense, if the sentence is said between injury and amputation. Although *is* is quite likely, *was* is entirely plausible.

Comment: @AndrewLeach I didn't say it couldn't.  Don't you mean "past tense"?

Comment: If the sentence is said between injury and amputation, I would prefer to use "his arm has been so badly injured..." though I agree you could also say "was so badly injured..."

Comment: No, I mean *must* could be present tense and still paired with *was*. However, I've now formatted the question better and a slightly different question has emerged. The OP is actually asking about adverb placement (even if that isn't actually the error).